# Xdebug version 2.2.0-dev

Tags: xdebug, lighttpd, komodo

I've succecfully installed xdebug 2.2.0-dev and my phpinfo() shows all the options, but I can't get it work with my IDE. In my IDE when I click at the option "Listener status" I see the number "Total connections" changing when I try to debug but the script simply doesn't stop at my breakpoint nor at the command xdebug_start(). I use a reverse shell to my server but when I telnet to Port 9000 on my localhost I get the error message: Name or service not known??? What can I do? Install the stable 2.1.2? When I start lighttpd I get this warning:

```
Xdebug requires Zend Engine API version 220060519.
The Zend Engine API version 220090626 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Derick Rethans at http://xdebug.org for a later version of Xdebug.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going wrong there. The big warning at the bottom only says that you have compiled Xdebug against the headers for the wrong PHP version. Do you have multiple sets of headers? If so: remove the ones you don't need.

Your telnet command is likely wrong, you use it like "telnet localhost 9000". Breakpoints not stopping is possible because you have not set-up path mappings in Komodo.

Comment: In fact I solve with a downgrade to xdebug 2.0.3 and a reverse shell connection. But I'm currently stuck update my vmware virtual machine on my localhost to use xdebug. I've a webserver and ftp succesfully installed and can use them from my host but I can't get xdebug working.